# Unity3d - reuse simple 2d animations into complex one (images inside)

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I created a simple crossbow arm animation for shooting (see fig. 1).

What I need now is to add this crossbow arm animation 2 times into crossbow shoot animation (see fig 2.). Is it possible to trigger start of subobject animation in parent object Animation Editor or Animator Editor?

[image]

If so - how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's entirely possible to animate each of the children along with the parent.
Open up the "Animation" window by navigating to "Window -> Animation".

Next, select the parent, and click on the red "Record" button in the Animation window. This will create a new animation clip. Give the clip a name and save it.

Now, you should see a button called "Add Curve". Click on this, and you should be able to select the children as well.

See attached screenshot.[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but that is not exactly what I meant.  I already have an animator object attached to child as well as simple animation created (the crossbow arm moves up and down as in fig.1). What I want is to create a parent object (the crossbow body) and attach 2 children to it: left crossbow arm and right crossbow arm which are exactly the same prefab, but one is rotated along y axis to create a mirrored copy. Now is there a way to fire both shoot animations (for both crossbow arms) from one of parent's object (crossbow body) animations?